# Why OrderedDict has this behavior

Tags: python, python-collections

In Python 2.7 I am having this behavior with OrderedDict

```
from collections import *
id(OrderedDict())
42101904
id(OrderedDict())
42071680
id(OrderedDict())
42071680
id(OrderedDict())
42071680
id(OrderedDict())
42071680
```

Why?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: nice find; I forgot I answered this before. :-)

Comment: Thank you guys, but now I am a bit more confused. I am trying to generate OrderedDict nested structures to generate xmls with xmltodict. So I call the children element from the children elements to append them to the parent element. When I call the method multiple times I get extra elements. Although apparently the variable is not stored inside the object.

Comment: @user3292520: that's an entirely *different* issue. You could make that a new question, but do include a good small sample to reproduce the behaviour you see.

Comment: I am going to do that, thanks for your kind help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not specific to `OrderedDict()`, Python is *reusing* freed memory to store the new object.

From the [`id()` function documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id):

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer (or long integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object **during its lifetime**. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same `id()` value.

You are creating a `OrderedDict()` object *only for the `id()` call*, and when that call completes there is nothing else referencing the object anymore. It is thus removed from memory again, and the *next* time you run `id(OrderedDict())` a new object is created at the exact same memory location.

Answer (score 1):

This is what the id() function does, it returns a unique identifier of an object, you are creating several objects, so you get different ids.